# Magento2.4 mysql to make all products a product type of simple

Tags: database, magento2.4

I imported all products into Magento2.4 using a plugin and just noticed 100 or so products have no product type which is causing them not to show on the website.

How can I run a query on the database directly to mark all products as simple products ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that would do the trick

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity
SET type_id = 'simple'
WHERE type_id IS NULL
```

You might need a reindex after.